# Raspberry Pi 2 Speech Synthesizer

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, raspberry-pi2

G'day, I'm building an app using Windows Universal and deploying it to a Raspberry Pi 2 using Windows IoT.

When I use this code via Universal and deploy it to my local machine, it works as expected.

However when I deploy it to my Pi, nothing happens, not even an error, does the Pi support Speech via IoT? Has anyone else ran into this problem before?

```
     private async  void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var SPEECH = new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();
        SpeechSynthesisStream SENTENCE = await SPEECH.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Hello World");
        mediaElement1.SetSource(SENTENCE, SENTENCE.ContentType);
        mediaElement1.Play();
    }
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that IoT has no speech languages installed by default. Can you check if [AllVoices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechsynthesis.speechsynthesizer.allvoices.aspx) contains any items?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, no it doesnt look like there are any voice installed via IoT, do you have recommendations on what i should do next?

Comment: I don't know how you install them on IoT (or if it's even possible). Checking if `AllVoices` returns anything is how you do runtime checks for whether speech should work or not.

Comment: Ok thank you Peter